# C# Clickonce custom installer interface

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce, .net-4.5

I have a windows form c# application that uses **clickonce** to install. I would like to create a custom installer instead of the default click once installer.

Is that possible? And if so is there is any example on how to do that?

Comment: I'll advice you use other third-party installers like `Advanced Installer` and `CreateInstallFree`

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there's no such thing as customizing the installer for ClickOnce applications.